# why do I get the error 'Invalid instance in App.root' in kivy python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I started learning how to use kivy today and it won't run, can someone help? here is my code:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ChildApp(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChildApp, self).__init__()
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Student name: "))
        self.s_name = TextInput()
        self.add_widget(self.s_name)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Student gender: "))
        self.s_gender = TextInput()
        self.add_widget(self.s_gender)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Student Marks: "))
        self.s_marks = TextInput()
        self.add_widget(self.s_marks)

class ParentApp(App):

    def build(self):
        App.root = ChildApp
        return App.root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ParentApp().run()
```

and this is the error that pops up:

```
[CRITICAL] App.root must be an _instance_ of Widget
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\admin\kivyLab\app.py", line 32, in <module>
     ParentApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 925, in _run_prepare
     raise Exception('Invalid instance in App.root')
 Exception: Invalid instance in App.root

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what did I do wrong? In the tutorials that I watched the code worked fine with no errors so I dont know what I did wrong

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really set `App.root` directly, the normal api is to return your intended root widget from the `build` method.

The specific problem is you set `App.root` to `ChildApp` instead of `ChildApp()`, i.e. you used the class itself instead of an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using kivy's Builder to load a string in the kivy lang:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
Screen:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows:2
        Label:
            text:"Student name: "
        TextInput:
            id:s_name
        Label:
            text:"Student gender: "
        TextInput:
            id:s_gender
"""

class ParentApp(App):
    screen = None
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return self.screen


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ParentApp().run()
```

As you can see it is a lot simpler and easier to read.
Comment below if any problems.

Comment: @yoda can you mark one of our answers as accepted so people can see the solution?